# Why do some medicines induce sleep?

Tags: molecular-biology, sleep, medicine

I have seen lot of people sleep or say that they are feeling sleepy after taking some medicines. Why? I mean, if a medicine acts on some cell of the body because that cell has got its receptors and other cells have receptor for another part of that molecule, then too why do a large range of medicine induce sleep?

This also points to a doubt that there are only one kind of receptors for sleep inducing medicines (the real ones not the ones which have sleep as side effect) or many? If many are there, then it can be possible that a large range of medicines induce sleep.

Is it due to induction of sleep gives relaxation and thus give time for action of other medicines? Or is it just a natural process? If latter, why only some?

I don't want metabolism, just a reason.

Comment: Potentially too broad here - many medicines induce drowsiness/sleep but they may (and probably are, particularly comparing sleep medication and those that induce drowsiness as a side effect) by different mechanisms. I think you may need to narrow this down a little.

Comment: I'm torn between flagging this as way too broad and thinking that it is a good opportunity to clear up basic misconceptions about drugs in an answer. In any case, I recently noticed that a standard book on pharmacology has three separate chapters entitled "how drugs act", this should give you a hint why the question is hard to answer in this state. Note that these were basic overview chapters, before delving into what specific classes of drugs do.

Comment: @rg255 can you suggest what specificity should be added?

Comment: You can answer three-four methods. Please give me the common ones.

Comment: @InfiniteLight I don't see how reducing it to three-four mechanisms will help. "Why are there many medicines which are H1 receptor antagonists" is not a good question, there is no good reason why there are several of them. Also, I wouldn't say that some mechanisms are more "common" than others, common by what count?

Comment: Common meaning here that many medicines exibit them

Comment: agree with @rg255 - too broad a question... but could easily just give a broad answer - drugs/medicines are not as specific are they are made out to be - any side effect, not just drowsiness, is an off-target effect

Comment: I don't understand the question? Is it why various parts of the same molecule can act on different receptors (atomic level), why a molecule can bind various receptors (molecular level), or why activation of different classes of neurons activate the same brain area (cellular and tissue level). Voted to close because it's unclear. Feel free to edit though. There's enough comments to make this question a cracker.

Comment: Hi - I agree with some previous comments that this is too broad because (and this is an assumption) the mechanisms will probably differ between medicines - if you have a few in mind then list them in the question and this will hopefully be answered (I am very interested to see an answer - particularly for antihistimines I take around this time of year... makes me very groggy some days)

Comment: Your edits do not fix the problems with this question

Comment: I just mean to ask that what can be the advantage of induction of sleep? Is it just as a side effect (like @VanceAlbaugh sujjested) or is it some part of a metabolism?

Comment: Is there any general relation which all pathways follow?

Comment: @InfiniteLight - within the body naturally occurring compounds as well as medications (i.e. legal and prescription) target a variety of receptors (even if drug companies or other people say they specifically target one single receptor in the body). Almost ALL drugs we prescribe to patients have side effects that are off-target effects. Anti-histamines are probably the most common class that cause people to be sleepy. Even though those drugs "act" through one type of histamine receptor, another type of brain histamine receptor is also targeted unintentionally - causing sleepiness.

Comment: @InfiniteLight - you are trying to ask why so many medications cause drowsiness in people. This is a common side effect of many drugs. There are a number of receptors that can cause drowsiness or sedating effects - there are too many drugs to name that act on these numerous receptors. These effects are off-target effects - which we call "side effects" in clinical medicine.

Comment: @VanceAlbaugh So, they are always side effects as drowsiness?

Comment: I mean drowsiness is always a side effect? I know others are there, I mean to ask if drowsiness is common to all or not

Comment: @InfiniteLight - drowsiness isn't always a side effect - it's just a common side effect for a lot of medications. Anticholinergic side effects (i.e. dry eyes, dry mouth) is another very common side effect we see. Those are mediated through cholinergic receptors. I will try and answer this question and give some citations for this stuff.

Comment: Give the answer in the answer column now. Don't just comment

Comment: Voting to reopen this question. I disagree that it should have been closed for being too broad, because I think this question can be answered with a relatively concise answer that clears up the misconceptions present in the original question.

Comment: Me too! @BryanKrause me too!